# Are HATEOAS link clickable

Tags: resteasy

I need to add links to my resteasy api xml and json output.
So I wrote a JAXB AtomLink class as follows

```
package samples;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="link", namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")

public class AtomLink {
    private String rel;
    private String href;
    private String type;

    public AtomLink() {}

    public AtomLink(String rel, String href, String type) {
        this.rel = rel;
        this.href = href;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public AtomLink(String rel, String href) {
        this(rel,href,"application/xml");
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getRel() {
        return rel;
    }
    public void setRel(String rel) {
        this.rel = rel;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getHref() {
        return href;
    }
    public void setHref(String href) {
        this.href = href;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

and set the link values in my JAXB xml or json object.
I got the output as follows. But the links are not clickable.

output:

```
<data xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<bucket id="2" name="2012-APR-09 12:05 AM">
<av_data unit="percent" value="100"/>
<data_count unit="#" value="10"/>
<pf_data unit="seconds" value="4.618"/>
</bucket>
<ns2:link href="http://localhost:8080/webapp/api/getrawdata?start=3&size=2" rel="next" type="application/xml"/>
</data>
```

What should i do to make the links clickable.

Thanks in advance.
Anitha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML and JSON are just text based representations of data.  The ability to click on a link depends upon the browser you are using to view the data ability to recognize a portion of that text as a link and render it as a hyperlink.